# Реализовывал классы геометрических фигур вылезла ошибка ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, классы

Что нужно исправить?

```
import math
fin = open('input.txt', 'r')
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')


class Point:
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0

    def __init__(self, a=0.0, b=0.0):
         self.x = a
         self.y = b


class Segment:
    a = Point()
    b = Point()

    @staticmethod
    def length(a, b):
        return math.sqrt((a.x - b.x) ** 2 + (a.y - b.y) ** 2)
        # return math.sqrt((A.x - B.x) ** 2 + (A.y - B.y) ** 2)

    def includes(self, point):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        if (point.x / point.y) == (b.x / b.y):
        if b.x >= a.x:
              if b.x >= point.x >= a.x:
                   return 'yes'
                    return 'no'
                else:
                    if b.x <= point.x <= a.x:
                        return 'yes'
                    return 'no'
            return 'no'

A = Point(float(fin.readline()), float(fin.readline()))
B = Point(float(fin.readline()), float(fin.readline()))
C = Point(float(fin.readline()), float(fin.readline()))
ss = Segment()
print(ss.includes(C))
```

Bот что выводит компилятор:

```
    if (point.x / point.y) == (b.x / b.y):
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точки `a` и `b` создаются внутри класса `Segment` без параметров, а это значит, что `a.x == 0`, `b.x == 0`, `a.y == 0`, `b.y == 0`.

При обработке оператора `(b.x / b.y)` на указанной средой строке возникает ошибка `float division by zero`, т.к. `b.x == 0` и `b.y == 0`, т.е. этот оператор - `0 / 0`.

На вопрос о том, откуда берётся ошибка, я ответил =)
Как исправлять - зависит от логики работы вашей программы.
Очевидно, исправить нужно то, что внутри класса точки всегда создаются с координатами `(0, 0)`. Именно это является корнем ошибки.